# Imap not receiving emails DOVECOT

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

I have installed Postfix and DOVECOT on centos.

I don't get any emails in inbox. I am sending mails to the server, I don't get an error message(emails to the sender) but the email is not received.

telnet domain 143 is working and I can connect and see my inbox. Thunderbird finds the server for imap, and I can also send emails but somehow I just can't receive emails.

The ports are opened in the firewall. The directory for the email account has write permission. I can create emails folders and I can see them in the system. The emails that I send are copied in the sent folders on the server.

The dns is ok.

Do you know why this could be?
If I send emails to a user that doesn't exists(test@domain), I get a email back like 550 No Such User Here

Comment: Did you check the logs and the config files? Postfix has such a complicated set of configuration files that it's nigh impossible for us to guess correctly what could be wrong without seeing a lot more detail regarding your configuration and/or log files.

Comment: To begin with, please, provide logs entries for both Postfix and Dovecot.

Comment: `550 No Such User Here` doesn't sound to me like Postfix. Are you sure you're talking to the correct SMTP server in the first place? [Postfix will normally respond with `User unknown in local recipients table`.](http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html)